JPQL how to JOIN FETCH a List with anymatch condition against the List
Given Entities:
@Entity
@Data
public class Collection {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String createdBy;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "collection")
  private List<CollectionAccess> collectionAccesses;

}

@Entity
@Data
public class CollectionAccess {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(
      foreignKey =
          @ForeignKey(
              value = ConstraintMode.PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
              name = "fk_collectionaccess_collection_collections_id"))
  private Collection collection;

  private Integer accessType;
  private LocalDateTime expirationAtUtc;
}

Given database:
select id, created_by from collection;
+----+------------+
| id | created_by |
+----+------------+
| 40 |   ABC123   |
+----+------------+

select * from collection_access;
+----+-------------+----------------------------+---------------+
| id | access_type | expiration_at_utc          | collection_id |
+----+-------------+----------------------------+---------------+
|  2 |           0 | 2011-12-03 03:15:30.000000 |            40 |
|  3 |           1 | 2011-12-03 03:15:30.000000 |            40 |
+----+-------------+----------------------------+---------------+

As you guys can see, the collection 40 has 2 collection_access 2 and 3.
I want to do JPQL select a Collection that:

Has id value is 40 AND
join fetch its CollectionAccess with a condition: if (createdBy match) OR (any CollectionAccess has accessType = 1 AND expirationAtUtc <= now). Why join fetch? Because of N + 1
The conditions against CollectionAccess is for matching Collection, NOT for filtering out any CollectionAccess inside Collection

(JOIN FETCH prevents N + 1 queries issue):
createQuery(
      "SELECT c FROM Collection c "
          + "LEFT JOIN FETCH c.collectionAccesses ca WHERE c.id = ?1 "
          + "AND (c.createdBy = ?2 OR (ca.accessType = ?3 AND ca.expirationAtUtc <= ?4))",
      Collection.class)
  .setParameter(1, id)
  .setParameter(2, "DUMMY DATA")
  .setParameter(3, 1)
  .setParameter(4, now)
  getSingleResult();

I expect that after executing this query, I will get a Collection have id 40 and its TWO CollectionAccess, but it give me ONLY ONE CollectionAccess which has id 3. PLEASE NOTE THAT I SET A DUMMY/WRONG DATA TO ?2
I have done some research and found this Stackoverflow topic (main idea is we will have both JOIN and JOIN FETCH).
Based on that, I changed the query to:
createQuery("SELECT c FROM Collection c LEFT JOIN c.collectionAccesses ca "
          + "LEFT JOIN FETCH c.collectionAccesses WHERE c.id = ?1 "
          + "AND (c.createdBy = ?2 OR (ca.accessType = ?3 AND ca.expirationAtUtc <= ?4))",
      Collection.class)
  .setParameter(1, id)
  .setParameter(2, "ABC123")  //NOW I SET CORRECT DATA TO ?2
  .setParameter(3, 1)
  .setParameter(4, now)
  getSingleResult();

Now it return to me DUPLICATED  that seems to be wrong!!
Then I decided to write nesting select and hope that it will work:
createQuery(
      "SELECT t FROM (SELECT c FROM Collection c "
              + "LEFT JOIN c.collectionAccesses ca WHERE c.id = ?1 "
              + "AND (c.createdBy = ?2 OR (ca.accessType = ?3 AND ca.expirationAtUtc <= ?4))) t "
              + "JOIN FETCH t.collectionAccesses ",
      Collection.class)
  .setParameter(1, id)
  .setParameter(2, "ABC123")
  .setParameter(3, 1)
  .setParameter(4, now)
  getSingleResult();

BUT NO LUCK:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Select item at position 1 in select list has no alias (aliases are required in CTEs and in subqueries occurring in from clause)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]

How can i archive this goal?

I want to do JPQL select a Collection that:

Has id value is 40 AND
join fetch its CollectionAccess with a condition: if (createdBy match) OR (any CollectionAccess has accessType = 1 AND expirationAtUtc
<= now)
The conditions against CollectionAccess is for matching Collection, NOT for filtering out any CollectionAccess inside
Collection



I expect that after executing this query, I will get a Collection have id 40 and its TWO CollectionAccess

Is it possible via JPQL? If not, could you suggest a solution?
Please help, thank you so much!!
========================================================
UPDATE:
Use Exists like Olivier suggested works, but 2 queries generated. Could it cause performace issue?


You can use an EXISTS subquery to test if at least one collection access fulfills the criteria:
List<Collection> list = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Collection c "
        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH c.collectionAccesses "
        + "WHERE c.id = ?1 "
        + "AND (c.createdBy = ?2 OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CollectionAccess ca WHERE ca.collection.id = c.id AND ca.accessType = ?3 AND ca.expirationAtUtc <= ?4))",
        Collection.class)
    .setParameter(1, id)
    .setParameter(2, "DUMMY DATA")
    .setParameter(3, 1)
    .setParameter(4, now)
    .getResultList();


Hi @Olivier, i would like to ask you why getResultList() but not getSingleResult()? Btw I see 2 queries which I don't really want. Could we have a better solution? Thanks

@SoT getSingleResult() throws a NoResultException when there is no result, which can happen here. That's why you should use getResultList().

@SoT "Btw I see 2 queries" There is a single query in my answer. Did you test it?

Yeah 1 query but has a subquery inside. I wonder how many queries jpa generate (i haven't test yet, will do in next hours)

there are 2 queries. Kindly check my UPDATE

@SoT I see only one SQL query in your screenshot.

line 8 from bottom-up. Is that considered a query? could it impact the performance? Kindly help! Thank you

@SoT It's a subquery, but there is still a single SQL query. And you can't really avoid it because, to test if "at least one collection access fulfills the criteria", you do need to read the collection accesses and check the criteria on them, which is precisely what the subquery does.

Sorry if I misunderstood your questions but in your very first attempt

I expect that after executing this query, I will get a Collection have id 40 and its TWO CollectionAccess, but it give me ONLY ONE CollectionAccess which has id 3. PLEASE NOTE THAT I SET A DUMMY/WRONG DATA TO ?2

Why did we expect2 entries here? I expect the query evaluates to
"SELECT c FROM Collection c "
      + "LEFT JOIN FETCH c.collectionAccesses ca WHERE c.id = 40 "
      + "AND (c.createdBy = "WrongData" OR (ca.accessType = 1 AND ca.expirationAtUtc <= Now))"

since c.createdBy is set to something wrong then only the data which evaluates to TRUE for the second sub clause of the OR condition would be returned. That would be only one row correct?

But I select Collection, not select CollectionAccess. Hibernate should not filter out CollectionAccess

You need to look beyond the ORM to understand this behavior.
The generated SQL query/result will look something like this :
select * from collection c
LEFT OUTER JOIN collectionAccesses ca 
on c.id = ca.collection_id 
WHERE c.id = ?1
AND (c.createdBy = ?2 OR (ca.accessType = ?3 AND ca.expirationAtUtc <= ?4))

    -----+------------+-------+----------------+----------------------------+---------------+
    c.id | c.createdBy| ca.id | ca.access_type | ca.expiration_at_utc       | ca.collection_id |
    -----+------------+-------+----------------+----------------------------+---------------+
      40 |     ABC123 |  2    |              0 | 2011-12-03 03:15:30.000000 |            40 |
      40 |     ABC123 |  3    |              1 | 2011-12-03 03:15:30.000000 |            40 |
    -----+------------+-------+----------------+----------------------------+---------------+

The getSingleResult() returns one record from the database, depending on the db provider it will add a hint like limit 1. So you'll  end up with one collection instance and one collectionAccess instance :
        -----+------------+-------+----------------+----------------------------+---------------+
        c.id | c.createdBy| ca.id | ca.access_type | ca.expiration_at_utc       | ca.collection_id |
        -----+------------+-------+----------------+----------------------------+---------------+
          40 |     ABC123 |  2    |              0 | 2011-12-03 03:15:30.000000 |            40 |            
        -----+------------+-------+----------------+----------------------------+---------------+

Since your query returns only one collection item (cause of the id condition), you can use the getResults() method and return the first object.
Hope this helps.

but, why in second case, I got duplicated colllection_access?

Hibernate does not return distinct results for a query with outer join fetching enabled for a collection. This is explained here by Gavin King himself :
https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-15782#jive_content_id_Hibernate_does_not_return_distinct_results_for_a_query_with_outer_join_fetching_enabled_for_a_collection_even_if_I_use_the_distinct_keyword

"depending on the db provider it will add a hint like limit 1" No, getSingleResult() throws a NonUniqueResultException if there is more than one result.

@HabibZ.Your link is 14 years old. Things changes over time. I believe they fixed that problem.
